# Mappings with specific properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vectors

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set and $K$ a field.

For $a\in X$ let $e_a\in K^X$ the map from $X$ to $K$ with $e_a(a)=1_K$ and $e_a(x)=0_K$ for all $x\in X$ with $x\neq a$.

For $f\in K^X$ let $\text{Sup}(f):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0_K\}\subseteq X$ the support of $f$.

**(a)** (i) Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $X:=[n]$. Determine for $1\leq i\leq n$ the column vector to $e_i$.

(ii) Let $1\leq m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $X:=[m]\times [n]$. Determine for $1\leq i\leq m$, $1\leq j\leq n$ the matrix to $e_{(i,j)}$.

(iii) Let $X=\mathbb{N}$. Determine for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence to $e_n$.

**(b)** Show that:

(i) For all $f,g\in K^X$ it holds that $\text{Sup}(f+g)\subseteq \text{Sup}(f)\cup \text{Sup}(g)$ and the equality holds if $\text{Sup}(f)\cap \text{Sup}(g)=\emptyset$.

(ii) For all $f\in K$ and $\lambda\in K$ it holds that $\text{Sup}(\lambda f)\subseteq \text{Sup}(f)$ and the equality holds if $\lambda\neq 0_K$.

**(c)** Let $K^{(X)}:=\{f\in K^X\mid |\text{Sup}(f)|<\infty\}$ the set of all maps from $X$ to $K$ with finite support. Show that $K^{(X)}$ is a subspace of $K^X$ (i.e. that $K^{(X)}\leq_K K^X$) and that $K^{(X)}=K^X \iff |X|<\infty$.

$$$$

Let's start with (a).

What is it meant by column vector to $e_i$ ? Is it a vector with $1$ at the $i$-th component and $0$ everywhere else?

- For **(b)(i)** I have done the following:

  Let $f,g\in K^X$. We have that $\text{Sup}(f+g)=\{x\in X\mid (f+g)(x)\neq 0_K\}$.

  It holds that $(f+g)(x)\neq 0_K\Rightarrow f(x)+g(x)\neq 0_K$. This implies that $f(x)\neq 0_K$ or $g(x)\neq 0_K$.

  Therefore this implies that \begin{align*}&\{x\in X\mid (f+g)(x)\neq 0_K\}\subset \{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0_K\}\cup \{x\in X\mid g(x)\neq 0_K\} \\ & \Rightarrow \text{Sup}(f+g)\subseteq \text{Sup}(f)\cup \text{Sup}(g) \end{align*}

  How can we show the part with the equality?
- For **(b)(ii)** I have done the following:

  Let $f\in K^X$ and $\lambda\in K$. We have that $\text{Sup}(\lambda f)=\{x\in X\mid (\lambda f)(x)\neq 0_K\}$.

  It holds that $(\lambda f)(x)\neq 0_K\Rightarrow \lambda f(x)\neq 0_K$. This implies that $f(x)\neq 0_K$.

  Therefore we get \begin{equation*}\{x\in X\mid (\lambda f)(x)\neq 0_K\}\subset \{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0_K\} \Rightarrow \text{Sup}(\lambda f)\subseteq \text{Sup}(f)\end{equation*}

  How can we show the part with the equality?

Is everything correct so far?

Could you give me a hint for the questions **(a)** and **(c) ** ?

Comment: Based on your definition, in the case that $X = \{1, 2, \dots, n\},$ we will have that $e_i(i) = 1$ and $e_i(j) = 0$ for all $1 \leq j \leq n$ such that $j \neq i.$ So, yes, in this case, $e_i$ can identified with the column vector with 1 in the $i$th place and 0s elsewhere.

Comment: For the first and second parts of (b), your proofs are correct.

Answer (score 1):

**(b)(i)**: We want to show that if $\operatorname{Supp}(f) \cap \operatorname{Supp}(g) = \emptyset,$ then $\operatorname{Supp}(f + g) = \operatorname{Supp}(f) \cup \operatorname{Supp}(g).$ By your work, it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Supp}(f) \cup \operatorname{Supp}(g) \subseteq \operatorname{Supp}(f + g).$ On the contrary, consider an element $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ or $g(x) \neq 0$ and $(f + g)(x) = 0.$ Considering that $(f + g)(x) = 0,$ we have that $f(x) = -g(x).$ Either $f(x) \neq 0$ or $g(x) \neq 0,$ but in either case, we have that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ so that $x \in \operatorname{Supp}(f) \cap \operatorname{Supp}(g)$ -- a contradiction.

**(b)(ii)**: We want to show that if $\lambda \neq 0,$ then $\operatorname{Supp}(\lambda f) = \operatorname{Supp}(f).$ By your work, it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Supp}(f) \subseteq \operatorname{Supp}(\lambda f).$ On the contrary, consider an element $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $(\lambda f)(x) = 0.$ We have that $\lambda f(x) = 0.$ By hypothesis that $K$ is a field, it follows that $\lambda = 0$ or $f(x) = 0.$ Considering that $f(x) \neq 0,$ we conclude that $\lambda = 0$ -- a contradiction.

For part **(a)(ii)**, use a similar idea to that of my comment above. Particularly, fix a pair $(i, j),$ and notice that $e_{i, j}(k, \ell) = 1$ whenever $k = i$ and $j = \ell$ and $e_{i, j}(k, \ell) = 0$ whenever $k \neq i$ or $\ell \neq j.$ Considering that $(i, j)$ is in the $i$th row and $j$th column, what will the resulting matrix look like?

For part **(a)(iii)**, you should find your answer by a process analogous to part **(a)(i)**.

For the first statement of part **(c)**, it suffices to prove that $K^{(X)}$ is closed under addition (the sum of two elements with finite support has finite support) and scalar multiplication (the product of an element with finite support and a scalar $\lambda \in K$ has finite support). Use both parts of **(b)**.

Comment: For the equivalence of part **(c)**, if $|X| < \infty,$ then as we have seen, $K^X$ is finite-dimensional, and the support of each map in $K^X$ is finite, hence we have that $\dim_K K^{(X)} = \dim_K K^X$ so that $K^{(X)} = K^X.$ Conversely, if $|X| = \infty,$ then we can construct a map in $K^X$ that does not have finite support: just take the sum of the maps $e_a$ for sufficiently many $a \in X.$

Comment: For **(a)(i)** the column vector to $e_i$ is a vector with $1$ at the $i$-th component and $0$ everywhere else.  

For **(a)(ii)** the matrix to $e_{(i,j)}$ isa matrix with $1$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column and $0$ everywhere else. 

For **(a)(iii)** the sequence to $e_n, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence with $1$ at the $i$-th position and $0$ everywhere else. 

Is that correct? When we say a vector/matrix/sequence **to** $e$ do we mean the one that is defined by $e$ ?

Comment: Exactly. Correct on all accounts.